# How to register only a single mouse click in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I am really new to Pygame and Python itself and am currently trying to make a game, but I have gotten stuck. I want that when I click my mouse button the value of a certain variable increases by one, but when I check to see if that happens, it registers several clicks.

The code is below. The part that I wanted to fix is at the end.

```
displayrolldice = False
turntaken = False


def displaydice1():
    if displayrolldice is True and randomnumber == 1:
        screen.blit(dice1, (166, 505))
        turntaken = True
        if turntaken is True:
            red.turnstaken += 1


def displaydice2():
    if displayrolldice is True and randomnumber == 2:
        screen.blit(dice2, (166, 505))
        turntaken = True
        if turntaken is True:
            red.turnstaken += 1


def displaydice3():
    if displayrolldice is True and randomnumber == 3:
        screen.blit(dice3, (166, 505))
        turntaken = True
        if turntaken is True:
            red.turnstaken += 1


def displaydice4():
    if displayrolldice is True and randomnumber == 4:
        screen.blit(dice4, (166, 505))
        turntaken = True
        if turntaken is True:
            red.turnstaken += 1


def displaydice5():
    if displayrolldice is True and randomnumber == 5:
        screen.blit(dice5, (166, 505))
        turntaken = True
        if turntaken is True:
            red.turnstaken += 1


def displaydice6():
    if displayrolldice is True and randomnumber == 6:
        screen.blit(dice6, (166, 505))
        turntaken = True
        if turntaken is True:
            red.turnstaken += 1


# gameloop ZARURI
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    displayludoboard()
    displaydicecontainer()
    displaydicenormal()
    displayredplayertoken(redtoken1x, redtoken1y)

    # roll dice boii
    mousecor = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouseXcor = mousecor[0]
    mouseYcor = mousecor[1]

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 164 < mouseXcor < 221 and 506 < mouseYcor < 560:
        displayrolldice = True
        print(red.turnstaken)
```

Comment: Process mouse button events inside the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop, i,e, `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 3:`.

Comment: Thank You So Much!!!!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Place your if statement here:

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # roll dice boii
        mousecor = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouseXcor = mousecor[0]
        mouseYcor = mousecor[1]

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 164 < mouseXcor < 221 and 506 < mouseYcor < 560:
            displayrolldice = True
            print(red.turnstaken)

    displayludoboard()
    displaydicecontainer()
    displaydicenormal()
    displayredplayertoken(redtoken1x, redtoken1y)
```

This way the event is triggered once for every mouse click.